# Error when I save model in Laravel. 'Call to a member function getKey() on a non-object'

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I try save my object in DB by this code:

```
$preview = new ProjectProductPreview();
$preview->user_id = $user_id;
$preview->path = $preview_url;
$preview->type = $type;
$preview->project_product_id = $product_id;
$preview->save();
```

And I got strange error. This error occurs when call save() method.
I have checked my laravel logs, there is this error. I can debug this precisely because in this case, error stack has only two positions

```
[2015-02-17 09:37:30] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function getKey() on a non-object' in /var/www/erp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php:133
    Stack trace:
    #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
    #1 {main} [] []
```

My model looks like:

```
class ProjectProductPreview extends BaseModel {

    protected $table = 'project_products_preview';


    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function project_product() {
        return $this->belongsTo('ProjectProduct', 'project_product_id');
    }

    public function projectProduct()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ProjectProduct', 'project_product_id');
    }

    public function message() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Message');
    }

    public function getThumb() {
        $path = $this->path;
        $thumb_path = str_replace('.jpg', '_70.jpg', $path);
        return $thumb_path;
    }

    public function fullPath() {
        return public_path($this->path);
    }

    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    public function getUrlAttribute() {
        $product_id = $this->project_product_id;

        return '/product/' . $product_id . '#' . $this->id;
    }

    public function isAccepted()
    {
        if($this->accepted==1){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        ProjectProductPreview::where('project_product_id',$this->project_product_id)->update(array('accepted'=>0));
        $this->accepted=1;
        $this->save();

        Event::fire('project_product_preview.accepted', array($this));
    }

    public function acceptRemove()
    {
        $this->accepted=0;
        $this->save();

        Event::fire('project_product_preview.remove_accept', array($this));
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there anything in your base model?

Comment: Also - are you sure it is exactly the `->save()` command doing the error? If you do `$preview->save(); dd('i got here');` - does that show up - or does it crash first?

Comment: You set neither guarded nor fillable properties, is that intended?

Comment: Yes, if I add exit before save() everything is OK, but when I add after save() I got error

Comment: Hmmm, I don't use fill() so I do not have set fillable and guarded properties. But I will check that suggestion [edit] It doesn't help

Comment: you got two identical relationships to $this->belongsTo('ProjectProduct', 'project_product_id'); which doesn't make sens although this might not cause the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about this, but I think this line

```
$preview->project_product_id = $product_id;
```

causes the issue. You have a relationship to `ProjectProduct` so you might want to do sth. like that actually:

```
$preview->projectProduct()->associate(ProjectProduct::find($product_id));
```

see [the laravel docs on inserting models](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models). Please also note that you have two identical realtionships to `ProjectProduct` which might cause unexpected behaviour as well. At least one is superflous.

```
// one can be removed
//public function project_product() {
//    return $this->belongsTo('ProjectProduct', 'project_product_id');
//}

public function projectProduct()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('ProjectProduct', 'project_product_id');
}
```

Comment: I remove redundant relationship and change association, but I still have the same error

Comment: have you done the same with the user relationship? Otherwise, try commenting out the function-bodies one by one to see what causes the issues.